# How can I replace specific text inside an excel cell with text from a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very large spreadsheet where I need to replace a word in one column with text from another on a large scale.

I need to replace one word (in this case it is [Rate]) with information from a different column.

ex: Fixed rate of [Rate] per kilowatt hour.

finished product: Fixed rate of 0.0652 (number found in different column) per kilowatt hour.

Is this possible on a large scale? There is 800 something of these that I need to update but my work application is rather slow and if I can streamline this it will save me hours of time.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it turns out though that because there are too many characters in the cells where I want to substitute that I won't be able to use the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitute function:

The information page is found at:
Syntax

```
SUBSTITUTE(text,old_text_or_reference,new_text_or_reference,inst)
```

Text:the text (as string) or reference in which you want to replace

Old_text:Text to be replaced in the string

New_text:Is the text or reference you want to replace old_text with.

inst: Not a compulsory variable. Is which consecutive number of the occurrence of the old_text that you want to replace.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/substitute-function-HP010062578.aspx

Comment: Just to add slightly to this, it might also be helpful to know that he can copy and then past special as values right over the formulae to convert them into regular text. CONTROL-c to copy and then hit (don't hold down) ALT, E, S then V.